# Not getting UIImageView Rounded Border while Added Multiplier for UIImageViwe

Tags: objective-c, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, uistoryboard

In Storyboard I applied Multiplier for height and width to UIImageView then I just want to rounded border so I used below code its not work for all iPhones.

```
_profileImgView.clipsToBounds = YES;
_profileImgView.layer.backgroundColor = color.CGColor;
_profileImgView.layer.cornerRadius =_profileImgView.frame.size.width/2;
_profileImgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:253.0/255.0 green:182.0/255.0 blue:43.0/255.0 alpha:100].CGColor;
_profileImgView.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
```

[image: In iPhone5s]

[image: In iPhone 7Plus]

Comment: are you working with autolayout and constraints? Are those lines of code called before the view is actually laid out (say, in viewDidLoad)?

Comment: Yes im working with Autolayouts and constraints . and I implemented this code in ViewDidLoad only. @il3v

Answer (score 0, accepted):

implement this code in same Viewcontroller class it is work for me

```
-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews
{
    [super viewDidLayoutSubviews];
    _profileImgView.clipsToBounds = YES;
_profileImgView.layer.backgroundColor = color.CGColor;
_profileImgView.layer.cornerRadius =_profileImgView.frame.size.width/2;
_profileImgView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:253.0/255.0 green:182.0/255.0 blue:43.0/255.0 alpha:100].CGColor;
_profileImgView.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your corner radius depends on your frame size, you need to update it whenever the frame size changes. If you are using storyboards for your design, you will get the frame size that is *in the design* when `viewDidLoad` is called. If the frame size differs for different devices, you will get the final size at a later point in time in the views `layoutSubviews` or possibly the view controller's `viewDidLayoutSubviews`.

My suggested solution is to sub-class `UIImageView` and put the specifics for the image view in `awakeFromNib` and `layoutSubviews`, then use this class instead of UIImageView where appropriate.

```
// CircularImageView.h
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface CircularImageView : UIImageView

@end

// CircularImageView.m
@implementation CircularImageView

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];

    self.clipsToBounds = YES;
    self.layer.borderColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:253.0/255.0 green:182.0/255.0 blue:43.0/255.0 alpha:100].CGColor;
    self.layer.borderWidth = 5.0f;
}

- (void)layoutSubviews {
    [super layoutSubviews];

    self.layer.cornerRadius = self.frame.size.width / 2;
}

@end
```